# Deleting in place with sed yielding 'extra characters' error on OSX

Tags: bash, macos, sed

I have a script with the following line:

```
sed -i.bak '2,${/rate = 3/d}' $FILENAME
```

The aim is to skip the first few lines of the file when performing the delete. I get the following error:

```
sed: 1: "2,${/rate = 3/d}": extra characters at the end of d command
```

How can I get it to work as intended?

Comment: does this work on osx? `seq 5 | sed '2,${/[35]/d}'` works on gnu sed.... probably syntax is different?

Comment: @Sundeep nope, same error. Maybe I'll just switch to GNU sed.

Comment: I vaguely remember seeing it on SO... something like `seq 5 | sed -e '2,${' -e '/[35]/d' -e '}'` ... check `man sed`, might have details on constructing such a sequence

Comment: or according to https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sed/9436/bsd-macos-sed-vs-gnu-sed-vs-the-posix-sed-specification#t=201705190731442748934, it might be `seq 5 | sed '2,${/[35]/d;}'` (note the ; added)

Comment: @sundeep - adding the ; is correct, suggest you make your comment into an answer

Comment: Perhaps `sed '1!/rate = 3/d' file` might work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `;` should help

```
$ seq 5 | sed '2,${/[35]/d;}'
1
2
4
```

Thanks to [@CRD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/568283/crd) as well for confirming this in the comments